# How to fix the Wordpress (Twenty Eleven) CSS Menu Alignment?

Tags: wordpress, css, wordpress-theming

Guys

I am having hard time tweaking a CSS part of the menu.

I have a website here at http://aaron.wordpresstiger.com where the last title "CONTACT" of the menu comes up with a line ahead and doesn't fits the menu. though i was successful in getting the "HOME" first menu item correctly fitting the menu but not the last one.

Can you please tell me what CSS i should add to fix this MENU problem. Also, please have a look i need the last item of the menu to be showing as same css as the first one (HOME).

I need the menu's items to look similar to the one here:
http://officialfacebooklikes.com/index.html (have a look at the last "CONTACT" which fits the menu correctly).

I look forward to hearing back for HELP :)

Regards
Muzammil Rafiq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your css you will want to add two styles

```
#access li {
    width: 25%;
}

#access li:last-of-type, li#menu-item-31{
    border-right: none !important;
    width:24% !important;
}
```

the first will make each menu element 1 quarter of the width... the second removes the right border on the last element and re-sizes it to fit properly on one line of the navigation bar.

the !important tags may not be necessary but they will ensure this works on the first go.

Comment: Thanks much Joe! I've added the above specified CSS in my style. but there is still a thing missing (I don't know if I'm correct), but when I hover over the last menu "CONTACT" it doesn't hover over the whole space, 5% of the space remains un-hovered (at right).

Comment: let me see if i can take a look in a few

Comment: Also, now after making a change the Hover image takes over the Border - Right, as you can see under http://aaron.wordpresstiger.com

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you want to create a horizontal menu you should float the list items. But as I can see from your example website you want the list items to be even in width, so you need to put those list item into containers, determing the width for each list container and float those. Also text-align center your a tags.

Good Luck!